# Dealing with line endings (carriage returns, EOLs) in AC_MSG_ERROR([foo])

Tags: autotools, autoconf, m4

So I need to use this autoconf macro, in a .m4 file of mine, this way:

```
if SomeCondition; then

    ...do_something...

    if OtherCondition; then
        AC_MSG_ERROR([This is the error message])
    fi
fi
```

For certainly good reasons, that error message is a bit long.

And today, I just decided that I wanted to add even some more extra info in the message.
But I don't want to make the line longer! So I wanted to break it in different lines. First thing I tried is:

```
if SomeCondition; then
    if OtherCondition; then
        AC_MSG_ERROR([
            Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
            Or you can also do blah blah blah
            (but take in account that it will disable blah blah)
        ])
    fi
fi
```

Of course this solution is not ideal, because when the message is presented, it is unnecessarily indented. The only real solution to fix this is using this ugly approach:

```
if SomeCondition; then
    if OtherCondition; then
        AC_MSG_ERROR([
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Or you can also do blah blah blah
(but take in account that it will disable blah blah)
        ])
    fi
fi
```

But, as I said, that is ugly. And I bet that some developer in the future will change it to "fix the indentation", without knowing that they are actually breaking it.

Is there a way to do this or will I hate autotools until the end of times?

Comment: There is a way to fix everything, but you will still hate the autotools until the end of time!

Comment: @WilliamPursell - Good advice. And if you go with `cmake` you will doomed to repeat the whole process.

Comment: Those who do not understand the autotools are doomed to reimplement them!

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
m4_define([my_m4_error],[
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Or you can also do blah blah blah
(but take in account that it will disable blah blah)
])

AS_IF([SomeCondition],[AS_IF([OtherCondition],[AC_MSG_ERROR([my_m4_error])])])
```

or since it's indented:

```
m4_define([my_m4_error],[m4_joinall([m4_newline([])],[],
          [Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.],
          [Or you can also do blah blah blah],
          [but take in account that it will disable blah blah])])
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not a suitable solution for me as I'm writing a macro, which means that the whole content of the document is already indented, as it's inside an AC_DEFUN declaration

Comment: Actually, the 2nd solution proposed would work I guess, but if you try to pretend that the first word of your answer "Simply" still applies to the 2nd solution proposed, I'm going to hang myself

Comment: The second solution isn't "simple", I agree.  There's a lot of options for M4Sugar string manipulations in the link posted by @BrettHale.

Answer (score 0):

Autoconf provides some m4 [string manipulation macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Text-processing-Macros) that are easy to use.
`m4_text_wrap` for example, provides indentation and maximum column width.

Comment: from that seems that m4_text_wrap doesn't provide what I'm looking for, I think `m4_normalize` is the closest to what I need, however the tabs that it removes are trailing only, not in the middle of the string :(